# Chilean, Canadian national transit through the US during COVID-19

Tags: visas, usa, transit, covid-19

Imagine a dual Chilean-Canadian national who wishes to fly from Chile to Canada in September, 2020. There are currently no flights directly from Chile to Canada (in better times there was an SCL-YYZ route).

Can this person safely use a ticket that transits through US airports given restrictions on entry due to COVID-19, assuming they meet the usual entry requirements for a Chilean (e.g., eligible for visa waiver program)?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the person has not been in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, or Brazil in the last 14 days, there are currently no restrictions on them traveling to the US by air as a visitor. So the person should be able to enter (including transit) the US on the Visa Waiver Program if otherwise eligible (e.g. having an ESTA since they are entering by air).

(Of course, as a Canadian citizen, they wouldn't even need to use the Visa Waiver Program; they can just enter the US as a B2 visitor on their Canadian passport without a visa.)

Comment: This answer is correct now...but it's worth noting that Covid rules are an ever- and quickly-changing field. What's OK now may not be OK tomorrow.